# Erro ao criar TabbarController em tempo de execução

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, iphone

Estou com um problema ao criar um *Tabbarcontroller* em tempo de execução em *objective-c*, quando chamo o método que cria o *tabbar* ocorre um erro:

> Thread 11: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, addess=0x3000000c)

Acredito que seja porque eu criei um *NavigationController* como *RootViewController* no AppDelegate, mas eu não posso utilizar o *tabbar* como *RootViewController*, porque só irei utilizar esse *tabbar* em determinada view, alguém tem idéia de como fazer isso sem ocorrer esse tipo de erro, segue o código.

```
-(void)criarTab{

MenuOpcao *vc1 = [[MenuOpcao alloc] initWithNibName:@"MenuOpcao" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
Carrinho *vc2 = [[Carrinho alloc] initWithNibName:@"Carrinho" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

NSMutableArray *topLevelControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[topLevelControllers addObject: vc1];
[topLevelControllers addObject: vc2];

vc1.title = @"Carrinho";
vc2.title = @"Tipos de Pratos";

vc1.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"filtro@2x"];
vc2.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"carrinho@2x"];

NSString *valorBagde =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%lu", (long)ContaCarrinho ];

vc2.tabBarItem.badgeValue=valorBagde;

tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabBarController.delegate = self;

@try {
   [tabBarController setViewControllers:topLevelControllers animated:YES];


    tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
    tabBarController.view.bounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    tabBarController.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    tabBarController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,h);
    [self.view addSubview:tabBarController.view];

    Tabok=2;

    [self.tabBarController.tabBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#ed2a69"]];




}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"%@", exception.reason);
    NSLog(@"%@", exception.description);
}
@finally {


}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Não é recomendado você dar push de um `UITabBarController` no seu app a partir de um `UINavigationViewController` mas sim, você tecnicamente pode fazer isso.

A forma mais simples de fazer o que você quer é esta:

```
// Construa seu tab bar normalmente
UITabBarController *tabBar = [UITabBarController new];
tabBar.delegate = self; // será que você precisa mesmo de um delegate neste caso?

// Adicione todos view controllers que você deseja renderizar nele.
[tabBar setViewControllers:viewControllers animated:NO];

// Se estiver usando size classes, você deve coloca-lo na tela assim
[viewController showViewController:tabBar];

// Senão
[viewController presentViewController:tabBar animated:YES];
```

Esse trecho abaixo é totalmente desnecessário

```
tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
tabBarController.view.bounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
tabBarController.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

tabBarController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,h);
[self.view addSubview:tabBarController.view];
```

E finalmente, evite ao MÁXIMO de usar `@try`, além de deixar a execução mais lenta, ele neste caso, não resolve o problema, se você estiver apenas usando o `@try` para depuração, é melhor você dar preferência aos logs de console ou o debugger do Xcode.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, esse problema eu já consegui resolver, agora tenho outro problema, agora quando pressionar um item do **tabbar** o **navigationbar** não é exibido você saberia como eu posso resolver isso?

Comment: Para cada item do seu `UITabView`, você tem que adicionar um `UINavigationView`. Se no caso, você quer que a barra de navegação esteja compartilhada entre todas as tabs, ai você terá que customizar um UITabView a partir de um UIViewController, [Apple não recomenda](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/CombiningViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH6-SW2) que um UINavigationController de push de um UITabBarController dentro dele mesmo.

Comment: Ficou claro, mas no caso eu utilizo um **tabbar** contento dois controles e também utilizo um **navigationbar**, o navigation somente tem botões mas utilizo o tab para navegar entre as telas.